# Heatmap with one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, heatmap

I have a dataframe with scores associated with every cell and I have the result of clustering (not related to the score) in one column of my dataframe:

```
>head(clust.labs)
type value cell
1    1   0.3    1
2    1   0.5    2
3    1  -0.3    3
4    1   0.5    4
5    1   0.3    5
6    1   0.3    6
```

I want to make a heatmap with one column representing the cells, samples coming in order and colors represent the scores(value). Currently I have made a heatmap that looks like below, I want the colored parts squished to one column and. I want a rectangle to be on the left representing samples. How can I do that?

```
 ggplot(data = clust.labs, mapping = aes(x = type,
                                         y = cell,
                                         fill = value)) +
    geom_tile() +
    xlab(label = "Sample")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using plot_ly. We have to convert the dataframe to a matrix and then run

```
as.matrix(as.numeric(clust.labs$value))->my.mat
colnames(my.mat)<-"KS.score"
rownames(my.mat)<-as.character(seq(1, length(my.mat[,1])))
cbind(my.mat, as.numeric(clust.labs$type))->my.mat
colnames(my.mat)<-c("KS.score", "Cluster")

plot_ly(z=my.mat, type="heatmap")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure how the output should look, but I decided to give it a try. Since you wanted to make a single column plot, you should add a variable that has the same value for all samples, which in this case I named `dummy`. Then, you can do the heatmap and add the rectangle using `geom_rect`. Finally, you can adjust the x-axis breaks to avoid showing the -0.5 and 0.5 labels.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(dummy = 1) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(dummy),
             y = cell,
             fill = value)) +
  #Add rectangle
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=factor(-0.5),
                xmax=factor(0.5),
                ymin=0.5,
                ymax=1.5),
            colour = "black",
            fill = "transparent") +
  geom_tile() +
  # Change breaks for x axis
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(0,1)) +
  xlab(label = "Sample")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this is extremely helpful, if only you can help me sort the y axis you have solved my problem. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: In which order do you want to sort the y axis?

Comment: so the cell column is essentially a sequence of numbers, the first x numbers are in sample 1, then the y numbers coming after that are in sample 2 and the z numbers coming after that are in sample 3. Currently that sequence is being messed up in the heatmap, I want the heatmap to retain the sequential order of cells then draw rectangles around the first x cells, etc.

Comment: Just change the following part of the code: `df |>
  arrange(type) |>
  mutate(dummy = 1,
         cellord = row_number()) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(dummy),
             y = cellord,
             fill = value))`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not fix the issue, I still get the same heatmap.

Comment: sample numbers correspond to the column named `type`? If that's the case, the previous code should work, if not, you might just need to change the column name in `arrange` from `type` to whatever the name of the column containining the sample number.

Comment: That is correct. It should work, I don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247298/discussion-between-jonathan-v-solorzano-and-a4747).